# How to fix a project that Interface-Builder fubar'd

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4

Help me un-fubar interface-builder in XCode4.

I created a button in interface-builder and defined an IBAction method for it in the view's code.  It ran fine.  Then I renamed the button's action method using XCode's refactor / rename tool.  It ran fine.

Then I deleted the button in interface-builder by selecting the button and hitting the delete key.  When I rebuilt the project the button is still there in the simulator.  Back in interface-builder, the button is gone.  There is no reference to the button in the code, but the button's IBAction method is still there.

To make matters worse, the button's original action method is getting called which of course throws a runtime exception of selector not found. When I do a project search for name of the original action method nothing is found, but the runtime is still trying to call it.  I did a "clean" and rebuild but no joy.

If I try to open the .xib file as ASCII Property list, it tells me the data has been corrupted.  (I figured that out.)

Other than deleting the .xib file and creating a new view, is there any way to fix this?

And what does "clean" do if it doesn't delete the binaries?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you open the .xib in a text editor, do you see anything odd?

Comment: @Jon Reid - the .xib in a text editor looks fine.  It looked like the objects in the xml representation of the xib were the same as the objects in the graphical representation in Interface Builder.  Somehow, XCode is hanging on to a stale reference somewhere.

Comment: After trying to reproduce this, I believe it was caused by my renaming the .xib file (which I neglected to mention when I posted the original question, sorry.)  I used the XCode "Refactor" tool to rename some of my objects, but I don't see how to rename a xib file using Refactor, so I just renamed it in the Project Navigator.  Probably not a good idea.

Comment: Ah, OK. There's nothing wrong with renaming xibs -- you just have to duplicate the change where the names are specified (either in code, or in other xibs).

Answer (score 1):

Try iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings. (To save time, Xcode tries to copy resources before launch only if those resources have changed, but if things have gone screwy…)

Comment: good tip.  I don't think that caused my fubar.  After trying to reproduce the problem, I think it was caused by my renaming one of my .xib files.

Comment: This is pretty old but still seems to happen. Just had an XIB that didn't change anything I did (adding buttons, setting targets, texts...). Deleting the app from the simulator helped.

Answer (score 1):

Clean did not work for me. In my experience, Xcode keeps a cache of the "compiled .xib" without regard to timestamps (try switching out a xib for one with the same name). My fix was to modify each view that needed to be refreshed. Very frustrating, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try going in Xcode to Build > Clean All targets, it should fix it

Comment: yeah, I tried Clean to no effect.  (BTW, in XCode 4, there is no Build menu.  Clean is under the Product menu, and there is no Clean All.  I guess it defaults to Clean All.)